# How to stub/mock Qt classes?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, qt, tdd, mocking

I am new to testing and TDD but decided to give it a try and learn. Currently I am trying to develop a class SettingsManager that would handle settings of my app. It would store app's state and when it closes SettingsManager will save the state using QSettings (and read when started). Now I want to mock QSettings so I my tests will not depend on random state. However, I could not find any sensible way of mocking/stubbing it because the method I need (QSettings::value()) is not virtual.

Perhaps I am doing something conceptually wrong? Or is there a way to mock that non-virtual method call?

Example: suppose I have this class:

```
class SettingsManager
{    
private:
    /* app state variables */
    QSettings *settings;
    bool m_objectsVisible;

public:

    SettingsManager(QSettings *settings)
    {
       this->settings = settings;
    }

    void readSettings()
    {
       m_objectsVisible = settings.value("Settings/ObjectsVisible").toBool();
    }

    bool objectsVisible()
    {
       return m_objectsVisible;
    }
};
```

And I want to test it that way (I used Hippomocks syntax just to give an idea)

```
void TestObjectsAreVisible() {
    MockRepository mocks;
    QSettings *settingsMock = mocks.ClassMock<QSettings>();
    mocks.ExpectCall(settingsMock , QSettings::value).With("Settings/ObjectsVisible").Return(true);
    SettingsManager *sManager = new SettingsManager(settingsMock);
    sManager->readSettings();
    assertTrue(sManager->objectsVisible);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are unit testing QSettings, but that is not a point of unit testing.

If you want to learn TDD, start with something simpler. For example, try to create a MVP triad of classes (model and presenter should have interfaces, while view is a qt class type). Then fully unit test model and presenter. The view should not have any logic - only qt calls.

Something like this :

```
struct View : (some qt object )
{
  View( PresenterIface &p_ ) : p(p_) {}

  void buttonClicked()
  {
    p.buttonClicked();
  }

  PresenterIface p;
};

struct Presenter : PresenterIface
{
 Presenter( ModelIface &m_ ) : m(m){}
 void buttonClicked()
 {
  m.setValue();
 }

 ModelIface &m;
};

struct Model : ModelIface
{
  void setValue()
  {
    // do something
  }
};
```

Comment: Seconded. Don't test QSettings. Test your class that saves your app settings.

Comment: I am not trying to test QSettings. I want to get different predefined return values from QSettings so I can be sure that the logic in my class behaves as expected. For example, what if the value returned by QSettings is empty or there is no such field in registry? Checking those conditions by hand is time consuming so I was wondering is there a way to mock QSettings?

Comment: @ashagi You can pass the object of type QSettings to the object of type SettingsManager, where you create a reference to that object. Then in your test, you can set various fields in the QSettings object, and check whether SettingsManager's methods return expected values.

Comment: Seems like it is the best option I can use. Anyway, I was hoping to get rid of that dependency using mock object in unit tests. Thank you for your suggestion!

Comment: The question is totally valid and the answer does not answer it at all. But the comment about just passing a different QSettings object seems to be the only good idea.